# Analog of "Spin" Chern-Simons Theory

Tags: chern-simons-theory, spin-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

3-dimensional Chern-Simons theories, with compact gauge group $G$, are determined by $H^4(BG)$. Looking at $U(1)$, with generator $c_1^2\in H^4(BU(1))=\mathbb{Z}$ for 1st Chern class $c_1$, there are infinitely many topological theories indexed by the level $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ (for class $k\cdot c_1^2$).  However, we can define other topological theories when an additional structure is put on the manifold. For a *spin structure*, this new "spin" U(1) Chern-Simons theory (in 3-dimensions) happens to exist for each *half-integer* $k\in\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}$. Main reason behind this is that for your 3-manifold $Y$, a spin 4-manifold $X$ which bounds it will have *even* intersection-pairing.
**[[Edit]]**: To expand on this, my source is Dijkgraaf/Witten. The "spin" topological theory is just taking your topological theory but requiring a choice of spin-structure. Given our functional $S=\frac{k}{4\pi^2}\int_XF^2$ modulo 1, the spin structure makes this $=k\cdot(\text{even number})$, and so we can now enlarge the levels to $\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}$.

My questions are (if they make sense): **Is there a structure on your manifold to have levels in $\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{Z}$ for some $n\ge 3$?**  **Can you formulate "spin-c" Chern Simons?**

From a physical-perspective I would guess *no* to the first one, because at least in the case of half-integers it corresponds to fermions in nature (and fermions/bosons are what we live with). But then again there is the Fractional Quantum Hall Effect...

Comment: You might be interested in considering fractional Pontryagin classes which turn up in higher gauge theory. There's certainly some Chern-Simons stuff there. For example: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/differential+string+structure and http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/differential+fivebrane+structure.

Comment: Could you please explain how your "spin" U(1)-CS theory is defined? Does it come from an action functional?

Comment: Spin structures corresponds to square roots of canonical bundle may be you need higher degree roots of it.

Comment: @Alexander: Isn't this only true for Riemann surfaces, whereas Chris talks about spin structures on 3-manifolds?

Comment: @Konrad Waldorf okay you are probably right I forgot the details. Any way it might be relevant if 3-fold = 2-fold \cross S^1. 

Comment: @Chris: sorry I still don't understand your definition. Is F the curvature of the U(1)-bundle? Why would it extend to X? What has S to do with the spin structures on X and Y?

Comment: Yea, $F/2\pi$ is $c_1(L)$ of some complex line bundle on $Y$. Since $Y$ is spin and $H_*(BU(1))$ is torsion-free, it is apparently true that the spin bordism group $\Omega_3(BU(1))$ vanishes, and hence $L$ and the spin structure can extend to $X$. The spin structure adds some *qualities* to $S$, such as that it is $k$ times an *even* integer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As David Roberts mentions in the comments above, indeed as one climbs up the [Whitehead tower of the orthogonal group](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Whitehead%20tower#OfTheOrthogonalGroup) the higher [Pontraygin classes](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Pontryagin%20class) become divisible by higher factors.

Notably in the next step, if you demand that also $\tfrac{1}{2}p_1$ vanishes, hence that you have not only a Spin-structure but even a [String structure](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/String%20structure), then the second Pontryagian class becomes divisble by 6.

In this case one can also divide the Lagrangian for 7-dimensional Chern-Simons theory by 6. This is discussed in

Fiorenza, Sati, Schreiber, *[Multiple M5-branes, String 2-connections, and 7d nonabelian Chern-Simons theory](http://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/7d+Chern-Simons+theory+and+the+5-brane)*.